# Remove splashscreen from ios cordova application

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have built an ios hybrid application using cordova 5.0.0. Whenever i launch the application the default cordova splash screen is there on the screen for some time. I want to restrict that. I have my custom screen in place of splash screen so i want to remove the splashscreen completely.

I have tried `navigator.splashscreen.hide();` as i have used cordova splashscreen plugin but no success.

Any help to remove the splash screen completely from my app

Answer (score 0):

Goto `.plist` and check `UILaunchimages` key, all the spash images are configured there.

**You can do any one of below:**

Modify that key and add your splash images to pick yours.

Use asset catalog.

Add images directly in project navigator with default name specification.